# DBeaver Automatically Appends END to CASE Statements

Tags: autocomplete, conditional-statements, dbeaver

It's a minor inconvenience but is there a way to turn this off?

I'm searching through all of the preferences and I don't see this. I have all of the other autocomplete features turned off.

I'm just a little old-school and autocomplete in general throws me off.

Comment: I absolutely can't stand this feature and it also cannot find a way to turn it off.